# Unidirectional M:M in Grails GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to have a Unidirectional M:M in Gorm?

e.g. 
I have a `Person` object and I have `TravelDestionion` object.

A person can have been to many travel destination and some of these travel destinations have of course had many people.  But, I never want to navigate from TravelDestination to Person.

Any tips?

Comment: Isn't adding `static belongsTo = Person` in `TravelDestination` solves the purpose (you cannot get to a particular Person from TravelDestination unless you access the join table), keeping the fact that there should always be a owning side of the relationship in m:m relations.

Comment: I don't understand that sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Read through the [description section](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html). I was focusing on the abstraction to the back reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can technically just not access the other side, but Grails is too helpful in this regard. For example when you want to associate a new `TravelDestination` instance with a `Person`, you add it to the person's `destinations` collection (or whatever you named it). But to ensure that both sides are in sync with what the database will look like after calling `save`, Grails adds the `Person` to the `TravelDestination`'s `persons` collection.

This can obviously be very expensive, e.g. with a User <-> Role relationship where 1,000,000 users have ROLE_USER, and one more gets that role, and that user becomes element #1,000,001 in the role's users collection, which gets loaded into memory by Hibernate to ensure uniqueness.

Check out this presentation where I discuss this and provide some performant options for reconfiguring the relationship without the potentially huge overhead of using collections to represent 1-many and many-many in GORM: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance